# Wicket Ajax update one dropdown to another

Tags: ajax, drop-down-menu, wicket

It seems like every time I learn a new platform, I have to re-solve this same old problem:
Update the choices in one drop down upon change of another dropdown, using Ajax.  This time
the framework is Wicket.

I have two entities I'll call Foo and Bar, and each Foo has a category, which is an enum internal to Foo.  Also, there exists a FooDAO with overloaded `find()` methods: the no-arg version returns all Foo in the DB, or a version with a paramater "filter" of Type Foo that returns all Foo matching filter in non-null values.

The client wants to associate Foos to Bars when creating a new Bar, but to filter the Foos by category before adding one.  So assume a handful of Foo already exist, each with a category.  A user goes to the create Bar page and the section to add a new Foo:  Dropdown A lists the categories, and upon choice of a category, Dropdown B is supposed to show the list of available Foo in that category, via an Ajax update.  Note that is no category is selected, dropdown B should show all available Foo.

My HTML looks a little like this:

```
<form wicket:id="createBarForm">
<div>
    <label>Category</label>
    <select wicket:id="category">
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Available Foo(s)</label>
    <select class="xlarge" wicket:id="selectedFoo">
    </select>
</div>
<button style="float:right;">Add</button>

<!-- and more Bar related fields -->
</form>
```

(The button will eventually get its own id and behavior, but right now the focus is on the lists.)

Here is the Java side (in the page's constructor method):

```
    createBarForm = new Form<Bar>("createBarForm",
            new CompoundPropertyModel<Bar>());

    final List<Foo> availableFoo = fooDao.find();

    final FormComponent<Foo> selectedFoo =
            new DropDownChoice<Foo>("selectedFoo", 
                    Model.of(new TechnologyFoo()), availableFoo);

    Foo.Category categoryStandin = null;

    final FormComponent<Foo.Category> fooCategory =
            new DropDownChoice<Foo.Category>
                ("fooCategory", Model.of(categoryStandin),
                        Arrays.asList(Foo.Category.values()));

    fooCategory.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            // re-set the form component
            availableFoo.clear();
            ((DropDownChoice<Foo>)selectedFoo).setChoices(availableFoo);
            createBarForm.remove(selectedFoo);

            Foo.Category newSelection =
                    fooCategory.getModelObject();
            if (newSelection != null) {
                Foo filter = new Foo();
                filter.setCategory(newSelection);
                availableFoo.addAll(fooDao.find(filter));
            }
            else {
                availableFoo.addAll(fooDao.find());
            }
            // re-fresh the form component
            ((DropDownChoice<Foo>)selectedFoo).setChoices(availableFoo);
            createBarForm.add(selectedFoo);
        }
    });

    createBarForm.add(fooCategory);
    createBarForm.add(selectedFoo);

    // etc.....
```

I haven't shown my `logger.debug` calls, but with them I am able to show that the `newSelection` is being captured correctly, and the DAO is returning the expected list of Foo.  Also, the `avaliableFoo` List does contain the required values as well.  However, Dropdown B always shows the full list of Foo, regardless
of the category selection.

Comment: Seeing as you've got the right answer, this is on a sidenote: I'd probably move the selection/choice updating code in the respective models of the dropdown choice components and just do the `target.addComponent()` call in the `onUpdate()` method, your code will be much easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got to add your DropDowns to the AjaxRequestTarget or they wouldn't be updated.

as in

```
target.add(selectedFoo);
```

Comment: I also has to add `selectedFoo.setOutputMarkupId(true);` but it seems to be working.